# Pgfplots ybar option draws tickmarks outside the plot area

Tags: pgfplots

I'm seeing x tick marks drawn outside the plot area when `ybar` is active. Is this expected, why, and how can it be prevented?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=Test,
    xlabel={X label},
    ylabel={Y label},
    ybar
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=Test,
    xlabel={X label},
    ylabel={Y label},
    %ybar
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: ybar]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. It makes sense to align the tick marks on the outside of the plot area, since especially the bottom ones are otherwise easily hidden by the columns of the plot (unless you're using `axis on top`, that is).

If you want the tick marks to be aligned on the inside of the plot area, set `xtick align=inside`.